# Finding numbers after a certain keyword using Python

Tags: python

I have a form (a string) that I want to process. The form can contain certain occurrences of this, for example: `>>1244`.

I need to grab every number after every occurrence of `>>`, but I'm not sure how. I'm thinking regex, but I'm terrible at it. I've read several similar questions, but the answers are wildly different, don't apply to this (they find the next WORD after a keyword) or sometimes use contradicting approaches.

What's the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not supposed to ask what the best way to do something is?

Comment: It's clearly stated: "The form can contain certain occurrences of this", that sentence tells you 1. "certain ocurrences", meaning they don't have to be at the beggining, also used in plural, meaning there can be several 2. I said "for example" right before the `>>1234` example, who would ever assume that it's always going to be 1234? Are you serious?

Comment: I retracted my comments. My fault for not reading carefully. The downvote is not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `findall()` with a [*positive look behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> s = ">>1244"
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=>>)\d+", s)
['1244']
>>>
>>> s = ">>1244 something >>500"
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=>>)\d+", s)
['1244', '500']
```

Here the `(?<=>>)\d+` expression would match one or more digits (`\d+`) that go after the `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions, try:

```
s = ">>1244 aaa >>112 >>344>>456 aaa sss >>345 >>aa  567"

import re

result = re.findall(">>(\d+)",s)

print result
```

Output:

```
['1244', '112', '344', '456', '345']
```

Remember that findall return a list of groups, if there are groups. You indicate groups using '(' and ')' to initiate and terminate respectively.

Look: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

If it's that simple to where you're only looking for a single occurance of `>>` and wanting to grab everything after that substring, you could do this:

```
mystring = "1234>>5678"
after = mystring.split(">>")[1]
```

That would split the string into a list at the ">>" and then grab the 2nd element of the list which would be everything after the ">>".